# How to set one submit button for multiple rows in a razor page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I get contacts and show all the addresses associated with each one in my asp.net core project. Below is the view

```
@model IEnumerable<ContactModel>
<table class="table table-stripped table-bordered text-center">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>no</th>
            <th>address</th>
            <th>confirm address</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @{
            int id = 0;
            foreach (var contact in Model)
            {
                id = id + 1;
                <tr>
                    <td>@id</td>
                    <td>@contact.Address</td>
                    <td>
                        <form method="post" asp-action="EditContacts">
                            <input type="hidden" value="@contact.Id" name="id" />
                            <input type="checkbox" class="h4 form-check-input single-checkbox" name="isValid" value="true" />
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
        
    </tbody>
</table>
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.single-checkbox').change(function() {
                $('.single-checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
                if ($('.single-checkbox:checked').length > 0) {
                    $('#submitButton').show();
                } else {
                    $('#submitButton').hide();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Below is the action corresponding to the view

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditContacts(int id, bool? isValid)
{
    var dbContact = await _db.ContactModels.FindAsync(id);
    var contactsWithInvalidAddress = await _db.ContactModels.Where(c=> c.PostalCode == dbContact.PostalCode && c.Id != id).ToListAsync();
    if(isValid == true)
    {
        dbContact.IsValid = true;
        foreach(var contact in contactsWithInvalidAddress)
        {
            contact.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return View();


}
```

The problem is If I add submit button to the form, it'll generate a new one for each row of addresses for one contact while I just need one submit button at the end of the form. I tried to change the position of the form tag in the razor page, but this time I got a binding problem; meaning even when I clicked on the the second row of the addresses it returned the id of the first row!

Answer (score 0):

I think  you need to restructure your form to encompass the entire table,
instead of having a separate form for each row by This way, you can have a single submit button for the entire form.
However, managing multiple checkboxes and ensuring that only the relevant id and isValid values are submitted when a checkbox is checked can be tricky.
the below  Razor view and controller action to handle this scenario
first adjust your view to include the entire table within a single form and use hidden inputs to manage which contact's 'isValid' status is being submitted.
You can use JS to update these hidden inputs based on the checkbox that was checked

```
@model IEnumerable<ContactModel>
<form method="post" asp-action="EditContacts">
    <table class="table table-stripped table-bordered text-center">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>no</th>
                <th>address</th>
                <th>confirm address</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @{
                int id = 0;
                foreach (var contact in Model)
                {
                    id++;
                    <tr>
                        <td>@id</td>
                        <td>@contact.Address</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="h4 form-check-input single-checkbox" name="SelectedContactId" value="@contact.Id" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" id="submitButton" style="display:none;">Submit</button>
</form>
```

then adjust your Js to handle showing and hiding the submit button based on checkbox action .
Since you now have a single form, the JavaScript logic for ensuring only one checkbox can be selected at a time remains the same.

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.single-checkbox').change(function() {
                $('.single-checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
                $('#submitButton').toggle($('.single-checkbox:checked').length > 0);
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Finally you can adjust  controller action to accept a potentially null `SelectedContactId`. This ID will represent the selected contact whose isValid status is being updated.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditContacts(int? SelectedContactId)
{
    if (SelectedContactId.HasValue)
    {
        var dbContact = await _db.ContactModels.FindAsync(SelectedContactId.Value);
        if (dbContact != null)
        {
            var contactsWithInvalidAddress = await _db.ContactModels.Where(c => c.PostalCode == dbContact.PostalCode && c.Id != SelectedContactId.Value).ToListAsync();

            dbContact.IsValid = true;
            foreach (var contact in contactsWithInvalidAddress)
            {
                contact.IsValid = false;
            }
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
    // Redirect to a relevant view or action after processing
    return RedirectToAction("YourViewName");
}
```